# MDM Server certificate to be used for SSL handshake with iPhone device

Tags: ios, x509certificate, mdm

I am trying to perform SSL Handshake between the iPhone device and my MDM Server. I have used iPhone configuration Utility (iPCU) and configured SCEP and MDM. SCEP works fine, the device receives the issued certificate from the CA.

In the MDM Payload, I have used the subject of the APNS certificate in the topic and entered the server IP with port 1234. As an identity, I have used the identity of the SCEP Certificate.

The iPhone generates the key and enrolls successfully, but then when it tries to install the profile by contacting the MDM server, I receive this error in the IPCU console:
**The server certificate for https://[IP here]:1234 is invalid**

In my MDM Server application which is programmed using C#.NET complains that **AuthenticationException:the SSPI has failed because the context has expired and can no longer be used.** So my question is, what certificate should I have on my MDM server - is it the MDM certificate received from the iOS Provision portal, the Apple push certificate of the customer or the certificate of the SCEP Server?

If someone could answer this question, I would be really grateful as I Have spent hours and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you using a self-signed cert on your web server?

Comment: Any chance you open sourced the MDM code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an iOS device is registering with your MDM service, it needs to know it is talking to the correct server. Your MDM server's SSL certificate helps it do this. This certificate is just like other web service certificates and will have as its CN (common name) the name used in the URL that the iOS device uses to enroll in your MDM service. For example, if the MDM enrollment URL is `https://mymdmservice.mydomain.com` the CN would be `mymdmservice.mydomain.com`.

The MDM service's certificate signing chain needs to be recognized by the mobile device. In particular, you could use any certificate issued by one of the usual registrars (e.g., Verisign or Comodo).

You *can* use a self-signed certificate, but you would have to add it to the device's trusted root certificate store (see http://fixmyitsystem.com/2012/01/install-corporate-pki-root-ca-on-ios.html).

Comment: it's still not trusting my certificate on the iphone

Comment: Should I be using the APNS certificate for the customer at this stage?

Comment: When you want a device managed by your MDM service to check-in, you send it a notification through Apple's push-notification service (hence, "APNS"). The APNS certificate Apple issues you ensures that only you can send notifications to your application. In short, the APNS certificate is used between your MDM service and the APNS service; the client device does not see the certificate directly. See also http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1

Comment: any break though ? i am also trying to have a ssl handshaking at ios client side but haven't succeeded yet . could somebody direct me to a detailed tutorial or some example. i have CA certificate at ios client in app bundle. when i hit the server with https request then i got authentication challenge and that time i need to initiate ssl handshaking by verifying server certificate with client certificate ...please advise :(

Comment: your problem can be simplified by using NDES to automatically issue certificates to your devices.