# The server ceritifcate for "url" is invalid, working on MDM in iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, https, mdm

I am working on MDM Setup on iOS, we followed the below blog to setup MDM with iOS. We have created all the files, when trying to install the configuration profile in device, it is throwing an error "The server ceritifcate for url is invalid".

URL: http://avibirnale.blogspot.in/2013/05/mdm-development-configuration-for-ios.html

Please find the below log to see the error in detail

```
    Oct 28 11:14:23 iPhone4S profiled[219] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Connection to https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin failed with error: NSError:
    Desc   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCHTTPTransactionErrorDomain
    Code   : 23002
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin"
    )
Oct 28 11:14:23 iPhone4S profiled[219] <Notice>: (Error) MDM: Cannot Authenticate. Error: NSError:
    Desc   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCHTTPTransactionErrorDomain
    Code   : 23002
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin"
    )
Oct 28 11:14:23 iPhone4S profiled[219] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Cannot install MDM “Mobile Device Management”. Error: NSError:
    Desc   : The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    Sugg   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    US Sugg: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "Mobile Device Management"
    )
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCHTTPTransactionErrorDomain
    Code   : 23002
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin"
    )
Oct 28 11:14:23 iPhone4S profiled[219] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Rolling back installation of profile “com.Test.mdm.profile”...
Oct 28 11:14:23 iPhone4S profiled[219] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Installation of profile “com.Test.mdm.profile” failed with error: NSError:
    Desc   : The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    Sugg   : The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    US Desc: The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    US Sugg: The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
    Code   : 1009
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "Test MDM Profile"
    )
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    Sugg   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    US Sugg: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "Mobile Device Management"
    )
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCHTTPTransactionErrorDomain
    Code   : 23002
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin"
    )
Oct 28 11:14:23 iPhone4S profiled[219] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Profile “com.Test.mdm.profile” failed to install with error: NSError:
    Desc   : Profile Failed to Install
    Sugg   : The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    US Desc: Profile Failed to Install
    US Sugg: The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    Sugg   : The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    US Desc: The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    US Sugg: The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
    Code   : 1009
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "Test MDM Profile"
    )
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    Sugg   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    US Sugg: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "Mobile Device Management"
    )
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCHTTPTransactionErrorDomain
    Code   : 23002
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin"
    )
Oct 28 11:14:24 iPhone4S Preferences[141] <Warning>: -[VPNConnectionStore reloadVPN]: The active VPN configuration has changed from  to (null)
Oct 28 11:14:24 iPhone4S Preferences[141] <Warning>: -[VPNBundleController _vpnConfigurationChanged:] (0x15e531d0:<VPNBundleController: 0x15e531d0>): _serviceCount(0), serviceCount(0), toggleInRootMenu(0), RootMenuItem(1)
Oct 28 11:14:24 iPhone4S profiled[219] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x14565fa0)
Oct 28 11:14:24 iPhone4S profiled[219] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Installation failed. Error: NSError:
    Desc   : Profile Installation Failed
    Sugg   : Profile Failed to Install
    US Desc: Profile Installation Failed
    US Sugg: Profile Failed to Install
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : Profile Failed to Install
    Sugg   : The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    US Desc: Profile Failed to Install
    US Sugg: The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    Sugg   : The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    US Desc: The profile “Test MDM Profile” could not be installed.
    US Sugg: The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
    Code   : 1009
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "Test MDM Profile"
    )
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    Sugg   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The payload “Mobile Device Management” could not be installed.
    US Sugg: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
    Code   : 4001
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "Mobile Device Management"
    )
    ...Underlying error:
    NSError:
    Desc   : The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    US Desc: The server certificate for “https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin” is invalid.
    Domain : MCHTTPTransactionErrorDomain
    Code   : 23002
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "https://ec2-54-172-70-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/MDM_Server/mdm/checkin"
    )
Oct 28 11:14:25 iPhone4S mc_mobile_tunnel[218] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: mc_mobile_tunnel shutting down.
```

Comment: If you will read that blog post you mentioned, you can find the solution below the blog post:Error #1

Comment: @SharonNathaniel: We did that, currently we are using JKS file only.

Comment: check if this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898018/mdm-server-certificate-to-be-used-for-ssl-handshake-with-iphone-device

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by uploading both server.p12 and server.crt in Credentials payload for that config profile.